# How do I train NN using keras.layers.Conv1D with my data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to experiment with Conv1D layer. I'm looking to run code from [the ml2 book](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/15_processing_sequences_using_rnns_and_cnns.ipynb) with my own data.

The code looks like this:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=20, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="valid",
                        input_shape=[None,1]),
    keras.layers.GRU(20, return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.GRU(20, return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(10))
])

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")

history = model.fit(bx, y, epochs=20)
```

The shape of bx:
(1256247, 120, 1)

The shape of y:
(1256247, 10)

What I mean to do is train prediction model which takes as input 120 values and puts out 10, and there are 1256247 records in the dataset.

When I start the execution, it fails with following error `Incompatible shapes: [32,59,10] vs. [32,10]`:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-02fdddb39c43> in <module>()
      9 model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
     10
---> 11 history = model.fit(bx, y, epochs=20)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    726         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    727         workers=workers,
--> 728         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    729 
    730   def evaluate(self,

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    322                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    323                 training_context=training_context,
--> 324                 total_epochs=epochs)
    325             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    326 

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    121         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    122       try:
--> 123         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    124       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    125         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     84     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     85     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 86                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     87 
     88   return execution_function

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    455 
    456     tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()
--> 457     result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    458     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
    459       self._call_counter.called_without_tracing()

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    518         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    519         # stateless function.
--> 520         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    521     else:
    522       canon_args, canon_kwds = \

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1821     """Calls a graph function specialized to the inputs."""
   1822     graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 1823     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1824 
   1825   @property

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs)
   1139          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,
   1140                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))),
-> 1141         self.captured_inputs)
   1142 
   1143   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1222     if executing_eagerly:
   1223       flat_outputs = forward_function.call(
-> 1224           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
   1225     else:
   1226       gradient_name = self._delayed_rewrite_functions.register()

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    509               inputs=args,
    510               attrs=("executor_type", executor_type, "config_proto", config),
--> 511               ctx=ctx)
    512         else:
    513           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     keras_symbolic_tensors = [

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [32,59,10] vs. [32,10]
     [[node BroadcastGradientArgs_2 (defined at /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_12526]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

How should I change the code to accept data in the format I'm providing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output shape of `keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(10))` is `(None, 59, 10)` instead of `(None, 10)`. You can first flatten the intermediate layer and apply dense layer. Also, `Conv1D` should have `(120,1)` input shape instead of `(None,1)`

```py
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=20, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="valid",
                        input_shape=[120,1]),
    keras.layers.GRU(20, return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.GRU(20, return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")

model.summary()
# _________________________________________________________________
# Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
# =================================================================
# conv1d_15 (Conv1D)           (None, 59, 20)            100       
# _________________________________________________________________
# gru_29 (GRU)                 (None, 59, 20)            2460      
# _________________________________________________________________
# gru_30 (GRU)                 (None, 59, 20)            2460      
# _________________________________________________________________
# flatten_3 (Flatten)          (None, 1180)              0         
# _________________________________________________________________
# dense_38 (Dense)             (None, 10)                11810     
# =================================================================
# Total params: 16,830
# Trainable params: 16,830
# Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: yes, that works. but what do I do with the TimeDistributed layer?

Comment: @ArsenZahray I think it is unnecessary in your case. TimeDistributed layer is a wrapper and it has no trainable parameters.